# how can i make I18N dynamic in gwt?

Tags: gwt, internationalization, gwt-platform

i'm using gwtp and i want to make my gwt application's I18N dynamic, i did something like[showcase example](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCheckBox)

is doing even though it is good but it is not the best way as it is reloading every time when locale is changing.

so i just want to change it to dynamic so that it allows me to change my locale at runtime,

thanks,

Comment: Looks to me like the showcase site does reload each time the locale changes.  Look at the querystring on the url.  What makes you believe differently?

Answer (score 0):

GWT compiles a different version of the code for each language in order to avoid users having to download all languages when they most likely only need their own.

If you do really want to make users download all languages because you want to change the language at runtime for whatever reason, you will have to do it in a completely different way.

There are many solutions for this (google Javascript Internationalization), none of which would involve the GWT way of doing things, as this is not very good practice and is discouraged by GWT.

By the way, if you mean you just want to change the locale at run time for testing, I hope you know you can just add the URL parameter:

```
http://your-url?locale=de
```

(for German locale)

Comment: yes it is completely different way and deviates from GWT,but still i need some solution to do this.

Comment: As you cannot use GWT directly to do this (unless you write some Widgets and code that do it manually), I would recommend JQuery. There is a nice plugin that does this: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/ Give it a go.

Comment: my intention is just to read the properties files at server side and obtain the properties files data and then i need to set them to my view based on keys. but i don't understand how to do that

Comment: Look, there are 3 ways of doing it: by using GWT (which compiles one version of the app for each language, then downloads only the language of the user to the client, but which can only change language by re-loading), by implementing it in JS statically (you download ALL languages, then you can quickly change the language in the client without reloading the app), or by dynamically fetching text (which would allow you to change the language dynamically without downloading the whole app, with the big disadvantages of being harder to implement and slower in general)... which one do you want??

Comment: for our application we are thinking reloading is the disadvantageous so i wish to know something about third method

Comment: @krrish I would try JQuery libraries such as  [i18next](http://jamuhl.github.com/i18next/) or [i18n-properties](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/). It's not hard to integrate GWT with these. But you will have to do some work, there is no way around that...